Why is there a difference between `FloatBarrier` and `clearpage`?
@David Carlisle wrote in a comment to a question

In answer to your question about floatbarrier it doesn't "act like"
\clearpage it is \clearpage that is its definition, \floatbarrier =
"if there are no pending floats do nothing, otherwise do \clearpage "

which is as well what the code in placeins.sty says -- as best I can read the code.
I was told  that marginpar material is treated specially and therefore FloatBarrier does not work for material in the margin - as demonstrated in the following MVE.
I am stuck with the question: why is FloatingBarrier (being the same) not working when \clearpage effectively pushes out the marginnotes? What I am missing? I read the very helpful article by Frank Mittelbach but did not understand how it applies to marginnotes.
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\filltext}{MARGIN NOTE TEXT Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Curabitur dictum gravida.  }

\newcommand{\maintext}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
    vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
    mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
    Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
    et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
    metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus
    eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
    quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
    faucibus. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue
    eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissimi }

\usepackage{marginfit}
\usepackage{placeins} % has no effect

%for lualatex (when expecting pdflatex) %  required
\let\pdfsavepos\savepos
\let\pdflastxpos\lastxpos
\let\pdflastypos\lastypos


\begin{document} 
    \maintext rutrum. note1 \marginpar{1 \filltext}
    \maintext rutrum. note2\marginpar{2 \filltext}
%   \FloatBarrier -- floatbarrier 
    \clearpage --clearpage--
    \maintext the paragraph should be broken and 
    the last line with the margin note  on the next 
    page. note3\marginpar{3 \filltext}
    
    \maintext rutrum. note4  \marginpar{4 \filltext}

    
\end{document}


marginpar are not floats, so the comment of mine that you quote does not apply.

@DavidCarlisle: But what are they then? and why is \clearpge cleaning them out, but \FloatBarrier does not?

I posted an answer expanding on the initial comment

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/724168/how-to-break-page-when-sidenote-marginnote-can-not-be-placed

@John Kormylo: Thank you for extensive explanation there! I still work on it...

@JohnKormylo: I just tried marginbarrier based on your code to my other question. nearly works (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272858/how-to-avoid-page-break-after-floatbarrier).

The quoted simplified description of FloatBarrier explains this:

In answer to your question about floatbarrier it doesn't "act like" \clearpage, it is \clearpage. That is its definition, \FloatBarrier = "if there are no pending floats do nothing, otherwise do \clearpage "

In this context "pending floats" means that the list of held over floats (like figures and tables) in \@deferlist is non empty.
You are using \marginpar from the contributed marginfit package. They are not floats and put nothing on \@deferlist so \FloatBarrier does nothing.
The marginfit package saves up the margin notes in its own custom list of tex boxes and then patches the latex output routine so that when a page is being made up in the output routine (where the page head and foot and floats are added) then margin notes are added to the margin. This applies whether the page is a "natural" page break or a forced break from \clearpage.

Thank you for explaining the mechanism used to put the margin notes into the page; now I partially understand. A small question remain: Is marginfix using the same mechanism? It shows the same behaviour.

@user855443 quick look at the source suggests that marginfix is closer to the standard latex \marginpar  which is closer to a float but never uses the deferlist (but does use some of the other float internal machinery)

Thank you for the information. I assume that the authors of marginfit and marginfix had good reasons, not to use deferlist. I just tried to adapt (sort of) a FloatBarrier to a marginbarrier. nearly working (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272858/how-to-avoid-page-break-after-floatbarrier)

@user855443 well for the package you used it wouldn't come up at all as they simply are not floats, just as \parbox or tabular  don't use \@deferlist. For the standard marginpar and marginparfix they are sort of floats but you never want them on deferlist to float an arbitrary number of pages away, they are strongly associated with a specific point in the document and are always output as soon as possible.
